# A combinatorics equality(need help proving it)

Tags: combinatorics

show that $\binom{n-1}{\frac{1}{2}(n+b)-1}-\binom{n-1}{\frac{1}{2}(n+b)}=\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}(b+n)}\frac{b}{n}$. Assuming $b>0$ and $b<n$

Just by thinking combinatorically, I don't see why the first combination is always larger than the second combination. and then ,I need help with proving it

Comment: The first one is always larger since $\frac12(n+b)>\frac12(n-1)$, and so $\frac12(n+b)-1$ is closer to the middle of that row in Pascal's triangle than $\frac12(n+b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to prove
$$
\binom{n-1}{\frac{1}{2}(n+b)-1}-\binom{n-1}{\frac{1}{2}(n+b)}=\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}(b+n)}\frac{b}{n}\tag1
$$
To do this, let $k=\frac12(n+b)$, and write everything with factorials:
$$
\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}-\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot \frac{2k-n}{n}\tag{$1'$}
$$
Now, cancel as much as possible. You can factor out $\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}$ from both sides. All that remains is
$$
\frac{1}{n-k}-\frac{1}{k}=\frac{n}{k(n-k)}\cdot \frac{2k-n}{n}\tag2
$$
So, prove $(2)$, the multiply by $\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}$ to get $(1')$, which is equivalent to $(1)$.

Comment: Sorry, Can you give some hint on how to prove (2)? induction on n?

Comment: @user42493 Algebraic manipulation.